# Upload de imagem num iframe usando AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

Tentei fazer upload de uma imagem via AJAX utilizando iframe, porém não faço ideia de como renderizo a imagem retornada da função depois do upload, segue o código:

```
<form target="frame" action="/painel/empresa/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formulario" id="formulario">

<input name="file" type="file"/>

<input type="submit" name="go" value="enviarrrr">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('input').change(function () {

    $('#formulario').submit();
    });

    $.getJSON('/echo/jsonp/?callback=?', function(e, progress) {

    });
  }
);
```

PHP:

```
public function upload(Request $request) {

    $data = $request->all();

    $teste = $data['file'];

    $nome = $teste->getClientOriginalName();



    return $nome;
}
```

Atualmente ele retorna apenas o nome da imagem dentro do iframe, como posso renderizar essa imagem?